# Volume AirPodsPRO too low with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, volume-control, headset

I have airpods1 and I had the same problem. I solved following this [Extremely low volume with AirPods (Ubuntu 19.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222666/extremely-low-volume-with-airpods-ubuntu-19-10) but with my airpodsPRO i don't know how to solve it.